# Running multiple sites Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, php, nginx, localhost

I'm beginner with Nginx (also using PHP 7.2) and I have no idea how to access multiple sites using separated folders. 
 
So as default folder I set `/home/user/php;`. 
There I have few folders named: `site1, site2, site3 etc`. 
Using terminal I start the server on my default folder with command `php -S localhost:8000`. 
And here's the problem, when I type in browser `localhost:8000/site1/` it shows what's in the index.php file, but messes with other files in that location. For example pictures. I have folder with png files located in `/php/site1/images/`. But they don't show up on the page in browser, because, according to terminal log, it's searching those png files in `/php/images/` (which not exists) and not in `/php/site1/images/`. Everything is searched in default server folder, not in subfolders with sites. How to change config file or what to do to make it read separate folders??

Here's my Nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites/available/default`):
https://pastebin.com/pZHgPkCZ

Comment: That php command is NOT USING NGINX . It is the php internal server, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php . I do not know enough about the php server to answer your question.

Comment: Please look at this https://devanswers.co/installing-nginx-ubuntu-18-04-multiple-domains/ use server blocks much like you would use virtualhost files in apache

Comment: @George Udosen of you read the question the OP is using php not nginx, so that is at least part of the problem let alone using nginx on a non default port .....

Comment: @Panther please could you be more explicit as I think OP has install php and nginx but can't get to install multiple site!

Comment: @George Udosen The OP stated "Using terminal I start the server on my default folder with command `php -S localhost:8000`"  they then " type in browser localhost:8000/site1/" . That is the php server, see my link in my first comment. Nginx will use port 80 by default

Comment: Thank you for your clarification I will add those details to the answer I am providing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps would be (assumptions:- Nginx installed):

1. Create server blocks for both or all your sites in the `/var/www/`folder:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /var/www/mytest1.com/public_html
   sudo mkdir -p /var/www/mytest2.com/public_html
   ```
2. Modify permissions to allow regular users read and write access:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/www/mytest1.com/public_html
   sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/www/mytest2.com/public_html
   ```
3. Set permissions so pages can be served correctly:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
   ```
4. Create two pages for the test sites:

   ```
   sudo echo "Welcome to mytest1.com!" > /var/www/mytest1.com/public_html/index.html
   sudo echo "Welcome to mytest2.com!" > /var/www/mytest2.com/public_html/index.html
   ```
5. Create Server Blocks:

   1. Copy over the default nginx homepage default file:

      ```
      sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/mytest1.com
      ```
   2. Edit the copied file:

      ```
      sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mytest1.com
      ```

      - Scroll down and change this `root /var/www/html;` to `root /var/www/mytest1.com/public_html;`
      - Change this `server_name _;` to `server_name mytest1.com www.mytest1.com;`
      - Change this `index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;` to this `index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;`
6. Make value for `fastcgi_pass socket` path is correct:

   - Run: `ls /var/run/php/`

     - Results:

       ```
       php7.2-fpm.pid php7.2-fpm.sock
       ```
     - Add the `php7.2-fpm.socket` location in the server block file if note pointing in the right direction and see that the location  portion of the file looks like so, remove the `#` to achieve this in some areas:

       ```
       ...
           location ~ \.php$ {
                                  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                 #
                 #                 # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 #                 # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                 #                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                  }
        ...
       ```
   - Close the editor and test nginx configuration with `sudo nginx -t`. See any errors repeats the steps backwards. For a valid syntax you will see:

     ```
      nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
      nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
     ```
7. Repeat `step 5 and 6` for the other site using `mytest2.com` where we had `mytest1.com` for site one, additionally for second site do the follow when editing the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mytest2.com` file change this:

   ```
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   ```

   - **Reason:**

     > Only one server block can have the default_server specification. This tells Nginx which block to revert to if the server_name requested does not match any of the available server blocks.
8. Create Symbolic links:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mytest1.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mytest2.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```
9. Remove the Symbolic link for default server block:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ```
10. Restart Nginx:

    ```
    sudo service nginx restart
    ```

11: Optional: Edit Hosts file:

```
 127.0.0.1 mytest1.com
 127.0.0.1 mytest2.com
```

Now go to your browser and type `localhost`, or `mysite1.com` if you made entries in the `/etc/hosts` file. Now also note that nginx listens on port `80` not `8080`. **Not the php server**.

Resource:

https://devanswers.co/installing-nginx-ubuntu-18-04-multiple-domains/

https://devanswers.co/installing-php-nginx-ubuntu-18-04/